# React conditionals in useEffect

Tags: reactjs

So I've managed to make a working timer and got stuck with another problem. I want to start and pause the timer with a click of a button. The button sets the state, when the state is true, the timer runs and pauses in the false state. But use effect can't be used in conditionals or nested functions, so does the conditional go inside useEffect and where exactly, if I need to also keep the empty array of useeffect?

```
const [miliseconds, setMiliseconds] = useState(99);
const [start, setStart] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
            const interval = setInterval(() => {
                setMiliseconds(miliseconds => miliseconds - 1);
            }, 1000);
            }, [])
<button onClick={() => setStart(!start)}>Start</button>
```

Comment: Just a note, milliseconds is not the best var name in this case. Number of runs or something along those lines is a lot better.

Answer (score 4):

you should approach it this way:

```
const [miliseconds, setMiliseconds] = useState(99);
const [start, setStart] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setMiliseconds(miliseconds => start ? miliseconds + 1 : miliseconds);
    }, 1000);
    return () => { // <- clear your interval
                clearInterval(interval); 
            }
}, [start]) // <- add start as dependency
<button onClick={() => setStart(!start)}>Start</button>
```

This way when start is true your timer counts upward and when it's false it stops, you can decide if you want to stop or countdown or whatever

The only thing to remember is to use `start` variable and decide based on its value in the `setInterval` callback function

Comment: Yup, it works. Completely forgot about inline conditionals. Thank you for the help.